# tengo dificultades con geoflutterfire al tratar de poner los conductores mas cercanos en el mapa

Tags: flutter

```dart
void getNearbyAnfitriones() {
        Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = _geofireProvider
            .getNearbyAnfitriones(_position.latitude, _position.longitude, 12);
    
        stream.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList) {
          for (MarkerId m in markers.keys) {
            bool remove = true;
    
            for (DocumentSnapshot d in documentList) {
              if (m.value == d.id) {
                remove = false;
              }
            }
            if (remove) {
              markers.remove(m);
              refresh();
            }
          }
          for (DocumentSnapshot d in documentList) {
           final GeoPoint point = d.data()['position']['geopoint'];
       *// esta linea `your text`anterior no me deja de mostrar error, gracias por su ayuda*
            addMarker(
              d.id,
              point.latitude,
              point.longitude,
              'Club Abierto',
              '',
              markerAnfitrion,
            );
          }
          refresh();
        });
      }
```

Comment: Buenas, te recomiendo que pases por [¿Cómo elaborar una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Recuerda ser concreto y directo cuando realices una pregunta. Darle el formato adecuado y sobre todo, en este tipo de preguntas, indicar cuál es el error que te arroja la consola o el ide.

Answer (score 0):

Sin el error, es complicado saber cuál es el problema, como te indico en el comentario.

Tampoco queda claro qué línea te está dando el error:
Esta: `final GeoPoint point = d.data()['position']['geopoint'];`
o:

```dart
 addMarker(
    d.id,
    point.latitude,
    point.longitude,
    'Club Abierto',
    '',
    markerAnfitrion,
);
```

En caso de ser esta: `final GeoPoint point = d.data()['position']['geopoint'];`  puede ser porque no estás haciendo los casts correctos y la variable no sepa que `['position']` es un objeto de tipo concreto y te lo está devolviendo como `dinamyc`. Por lo que pasaría lo mismo con el `['geopoint']`.

Como no indicas el fallo, no sé si sea este el error o no. Si lo es, recuerda aclarar la pregunta y marcar la respuesta como correcta, para poder ayudar a otras personas. Y si no lo es, edita la pregunta y aclárala, para obtener más ayuda.